# Setting the size in RN's ImageBackground equal to the image used

Tags: reactjs, react-native, imagebackground

I'm using ImageBackground from React Native and I'm using a background. I would like to use the size of the background to set the size of the element.

```
<ImageBackground source={require("../images/Image.png")}>
  <Text>Hello World!</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Define `height` of your `ImageBackground`

```
<ImageBackground style={{height: 300}} source={require("../images/Image.png")}>
  <Text>Hello World!</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```

Comment: Thanks, I want that height to be the same size as Image.png, though. Maybe it's not clear on the comments!

Comment: Same with? Can you please elaborate it more.